# Как создать файл для cron?

Tags: cron, linux

Уважаемые любители Linux!

Помогите, пожалуйста, создать файл расписания под пользователем alexander и там написать всего одну строчку ежемесячного запуска файла. Команда crontab -e открывает и дает редактировать файл, но не сохраняет его. При повторном запуске этой команды файл открывается без моей команды.

Comment: Залогинься под рутом пропиши строку сохрани и все.

Comment: Думаю, нужно разбираться с редактором, который вызывается при `crontab -e` и учиться работать с ним. Наверное, вы просто не умеете в нём сохранять. )) Может, это vi.

Answer (score 4):

1. Заходим под пользователем 'alexander'
2. Вводим в консоли: `echo '* * * */1 *` (команда запуска файла)' > alexcron
3. Вводим в консоли: `crontab alexcron`
4. Проверяем нашу запись: `crontab -l`    должна появиться запись `* * * */1 *` (команда запуска файла)
5. Выполняем в консоли: `export EDITOR=nano`
6. Редактируем: `crontab -e`  -->откроется редактор nano,сделать изменения в файле, затем
7. 'Ctr+X', затем 'Y', затем 'Enter'
8. Проверяем наш измененный файл: `crontab -l`

Answer (score 0):

Из под рута сохраняйте, там с редактором nano стандартным, кажись, идет Ctrl+O.

Answer (score 0):

sudo nano /etc/crontab, не?

Answer (score 0):

По умолчанию, в качестве редактора,в некоторых дистрибутивах линукс, используется vi.Для создания своего задания для cron наберите команду: crontab -e и нажимаете Enter. Вы попадаете в командный режим редактора vi. Чтобы добавить строку и перейти в режим редактирования нажмите Ctrl-o. Вводите необходимую строку задания и нажмите Shift-:(двоеточие) Вы попадаете вновь в коммандный режим. На это указывает приглашение (:) в левом нижнем углу редактора. Для того, чтобы сохранить задание после двоеточия наберите wq и нажмите Enter. Задание будет добавлено. Проверить добавленное задание можно с помощью команды crontab -l

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo crontab -u alexander -e
```

Если нужен лог

```
* * * */1 *` /path/to/script &>> /path/to/logs/cron.log
```

Если НЕ нужен лог

```
* * * */1 *` /path/to/script &> /dev/null
```

В `vim` сохранять `Esc :wq`.